# my JS age calculator app isn't working properly

Tags: javascript

```
const calc=()=>{  
currentDate= new Date();  
currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth()+1);  
daysb4process=inputDays.firstChild.value;  
monthsb4process=inputMonths.firstChild.value;  
yearsb4process=inputYears.firstChild.value;  
pastDate= new Date();  
pastDate.setFullYear(yearsb4process);  
pastDate.setMonth(monthsb4process);  
pastDate.setDate(daysb4process);  
const timeDiff=currentDate-pastDate;  
console.log([daysb4process,monthsb4process,yearsb4process]);  
const msid = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;  
const msiy=msid*365;  
const years=Math.floor(timeDiff/msiy);  
const remainingDays=Math.floor(timeDiff/msid)%365;  
const months=Math.floor(remainingDays/30);  
console.log("remainingDays: ",remainingDays);  
const days=remainingDays%(sum([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],months))-countLeapYears(yearsb4process);  
console.log([years,months,days]);  
return [years,months,days];  
}
```

i wrote this JS function to be executed when the user enters a specific date and clicks a button, the function then turns that date into a Date object and subtracts it from the current date returning the difference in milliseconds, it then takes that `timeDiff` and turn it into days, turn that number into years and take the `remainingDays` and turns them into months and what's left is the number of days after subtracting the number of leap years' days.

the way i thought of it and see it, it should work fine, but it doesn't, for some reason the result is missing or having additional days(for currentDate='2023-07-29' and pastDate='2003-03-06' it gives '20 yrs 4 months 24 days' but it should be 23 days), and sometimes it gives the days in minus. i tried with multiple dates like the same day and month of the currentDate and tried to fix the code according to, but it still doesn't work as needed and at this point i don't really know if the bug is in the code or my logic.

here's the 2 functions `sum` and `countLeapYears` used in the above code:

```
const countLeapYears = (pastyear) => {  
let count=0;  
for (let i = pastyear; i < currentYear+1; i++) {  
    if ((i % 4 === 0) && (i % 100 !== 0) || (i % 400 === 0)) {  
        count++;  
    }  
}  
return count;  
}  
const sum = (arr,n) => {  
var sum=0;  
if (n==0) return 30;  
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    sum+=arr[i];  
}  
return sum;  
}
```

sorry if my question was too long or i am not clear enough; this is my first time asking on the site, so i would really appreciate any tips on how to improve my way along with my code <3.

Comment: I don't see you calling `countLeapYears` anywhere.

Comment: @TimRoberts  i did use it when declaring the days variable, 4th line from the botton

Comment: sidenote: please format your code, you're asking humans to read it. "As concise as possible" is the opposite of good, easy to read code. And add `let` or `const` as part of variables declarations. Don't use bare variables (unless you _really_ like esoteric bugs)

Comment: Why do you increment `currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth()+1);`?

Comment: @jabaa because Date().getMonth() have a range of 0 - 11, so March is 2 and April is 3, so you have to increase it by 1 to get the right value.

Comment: `currentDate= new Date();` stores the current date for today. `currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth()+1);` sets `currentDate` to next month. Is this expected? If yes, the variable name is misleading. It should be `nextMonth`. But somehow I think, this is a bug. This would explain the incorrect number of days. July has 31 days. June has only 30 days. Using the wrong month can cause an error of one day.

Comment: What is `currentYear`? You count leap years and subtract them. But you can only subtract a leap year in the birth year if the birthday is before 29th Feb and you can only subtract a leap year in the current year if today is after 28th Feb.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the age correctly, you can simplify the logic by creating two date objects (one for the current date and one for the birthday), and then compare the year, month, and day separately. Here's a simpler version of age calculation logic:

```
const calculateAge = (birthday) => {
    let now = new Date();
    let birthDate = new Date(birthday); // birthday is a date

    let age = now.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    let m = now.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && now.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }

    return age;
}
```

Comment: Where are the months and days?